# Nested IF / AND / OR statement

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement

I have a formula that I can seem to get most of the way there, but can't make the final jump. Here is the scenario. If any cell in an array (B2:B4) is not blank, then cell B9 should populate a text value OR if any cell in a different array (D6:D9) has a text value, then again cell B9 should populate with a different text value. Finally, if both arrays meet the specific criteria, then cell B9 should populate with a third text value.

Here is what I have that works. This formula returns a value of "**Correct**" id `B2:B4` is not blank OR if `D7:D9` contains the text "**Plus**" it returns a value of "Plus". Otherwise it leaves cell B9 blank.

```
=IF(OR(B2<>"",B3<>"",B4<>""),"Correct",IF(OR(D7="Plus",D8="Plus",D6="Plus"),"Plus","Blank"))
```

This AND formula returns "Correct+Plus" if both of the criteria above are met.

```
=IF(AND(OR(B2<>"",B3<>"",B4<>""),(OR(D7="Plus",D8="Plus",D6="Plus”))),”Correct+Plus”,”Correct or Plus or Nothing")
```

I can't seem to get the formula that combines both. If array 1 is not blank, return "Correct". If array 2 is "Plus" return "Plus". If array 1 is not blank AND array 2 is "Plus", return "Correct+Plus".

Answer (score 0):

Your narrative is different than you formula,  You state that array 1 need to not have any blanks, yet you use an `OR` which states that if any are not blank it will return true and only false when all three are blank.  If that is the case use this:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTBLANK(B2:B4)<3,COUNTIF(D6:D8,"Plus")),"Correct+Plus","Correct or Plus or Nothing")
```

But if you want to ensure that non of the first array are blank then use this:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTBLANK(B2:B4)=0,COUNTIF(D6:D8,"Plus")),"Correct+Plus","Correct or Plus or Nothing")
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. That one doesn't return my OR value.

Comment: I did find the right one, may have too many functions, but it works. =IF(AND(OR(B2<>"",B3<>"",B4<>""),(OR(D7="Plus",D8="Plus",D6="Plus"))),"DAM+Plus",IF(OR(B2<>"",B3<>"",B4<>""),"DAM",IF(OR(D7="Plus",D8="Plus",D6="Plus"),"Plus","Blank")))

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found that works.

=IF(AND(OR(B2<>"",B3<>"",B4<>""),(OR(D7="Plus",D8="Plus",D6="Plus"))),"Correct+Plus",IF(OR(B2<>"",B3<>"",B4<>""),"Correct",IF(OR(D7="Plus",D8="Plus",D6="Plus"),"Plus","Blank")))

Answer (score 0):

Alternate formula that will work for you:

```
=CHOOSE((COUNTBLANK(B2:B4)<3)+(COUNTIF(D6:D8,"plus")>0)*2+1,"Blank","Correct","Plus","Correct+Plus")
```